# How to generate hiberate POJO classes from DB tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have an sql script that contains DDL's for creating many number of tables, simply will execute this script for creating tables in db.

Now i want to use hibernate to perform CURD operations on that tables, but going through each table for creating POJO's will take time. So, is there any way to generate those POJO with JPA annotations using those DB tables which are already created?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/ can generate entities from database if you are using eclipse IDE

Comment: What if you're not using Eclipse? (I hate Eclipse.)

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse you can use the **Telosys Tools** plugin 
( http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools )
It works from an existing database and generates different kinds of source files
typically Java beans with JPA annotations
See http://tools.telosys.org
and the tutorials : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/